# Spring cache with ehcache issue if cache is in lib

Tags: spring, ehcache

We have one lib where our dao is packaged and dao method are annotated with @Cacheable. When we run our junit, caching is working as expected.

When we use this lib in web app and load lib's application context then it is not doing anything about caching.

What could be wrong in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can see is that your DAO when loaded in your application are not processed by Spring. In that case, no proxy would be created and so caching would not be applied.

There are different ways to verify that. You could try injecting something and verifying at runtime it has been injected. You could print a stack trace when the DAO is used and verify it is wrapped by a proxy. And other ways ...